# Using the AMORE package on R

Tags: r, neural-network

If anyone is familiar with the AMORE package on R and can spare 5 minutes of their time, I would appreciate their help.

**My problem:**

I am a Neural Network/R newbie, who is attempting to train a neural network with 15 inputs and 1 output using AMORE. I am using a dataset that has 16 columns (15 columns for inputs and 1 for outputs) and 124 rows (1 row per unit).

My interpretation is that I don't need to distinguish a training set from testing set for the function to work. Instead, I have created subsets from my dataset, and then vectors from my subsets, in order to provide the 'inputs' and 'targets' for the function. However, I am not sure that I have interpreted this correctly.

The function runs without error but I remain suspicious.

**This is what I wrote:**

```
mydata <- read_excel("R/win-library/4.0/R Data.xlsx")

input->mydata[1:124,3:17]
output->mydata[1:124,2]
P = as.vector(input,mode = 'numeric')
TARGET = as.vector(output,mode = 'numeric')

library(AMORE)

#Feedforward network with 1 hidden layer
net<-newff(n.neurons = c(15,4,1),
           learning.rate.global = 0.01,
           momentum.global = 0.9,
           error.criterium = "LMS",
           Stao=NA, hidden.layer="sigmoid",
           output.layer = "sigmoid",
           method = "ADAPTgdwm")

result<- train(net,P,TARGET, error.criterium = "LMS",report = TRUE,
               n.shows = 15,show.step = 200)

y<-sim(result$net,TARGET)
plot(mydata[,1],y,col='blue', pch='+')
points(P,TARGET,col='red',pch='x')
```

**Cheers to the good samaritan that helps...**

Comment: It is better if you use `keras` package in `R`. If you are open to that option I could add a solution for you in `keras`!

Comment: I am open to that!

Comment: I have added an option with `keras` in `R` please check and I hope that is useful for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest as an option using neural networks architecture from `keras` package in `R`. I will add an example of how to train a neural network using functions from this well-known package. We will also use `rsample` package in order to split our data into train and test set. Next the code:

We will use `iris` dataset for this example. The main libraries are `keras` and `dplyr` so check if you have installed it.

Initially, we have to prepare the data. We use `rsample` to split the data into train and test set so that the same proportion of target variable is kept in the subsets of data:

```
#Libraries
library(rsample)
library(keras) 
library(dplyr)
##### Data preparation
Input <- iris
#Change name of target variable
Input %>% rename(Model1=Species) -> Input
# Create training (70%) and test (30%) sets
# stratified sampling with the rsample package
set.seed(123)
split_strat <- initial_split(Input, prop = 0.7,
                             strata = 'Model1')
train_strat <- training(split_strat)
test_strat <- testing(split_strat)
# consistent response ratio between train & test
table(Input$Model1) %>% prop.table()
table(train_strat$Model1) %>% prop.table()
table(test_strat$Model1) %>% prop.table()
```

With previous step, we can sketch the architecture for our neural network. The functions of this package take data as matrices and the target variable because of codification must start from zero. In our data the target variable `Model1` (column 5) has three classes and we also have to transform into matrix. The function `to_categorical` is useful for that. With next code we prepare our data:

```
##### Neural nets
#Input data
mn_x <- train_strat[,-5]
mn_x <- as.matrix(mn_x)
mn_y <- train_strat[,5]
mn_y <- as.integer(as.numeric(mn_y)-1)
# Encode response
mn_y <- to_categorical(mn_y,num_classes = 3)
# Get number of features, which we'll use in our model
p <- ncol(mn_x)
```

We also have to determine the number of features in our model, which is required by the architecture. This action belongs to `p` in our code. With these inputs, we can design the neural network. Key functions are `layer_dense()` which allows the addition of neurons. In this function we have to define the activation function. We will define a traditional `relu` function. In the final layer you have to define as units the number of classes in your target variable and the activation function. If your problem is binary, you should define a sigmoid function. In our case, it is a multiclass problem so we will define softmax function. You can add as many layers before final output using pipes from `dplyr`.

Once the layers are defined you must set backpropagation with `compile()` function. Essential arguments are `loss`, `optimizer` and `metrics`. We will use `categorical_crossentropy` for `loss`, `accuracy` for metrics and the `optimizer` as `optimizer_rmsprop()`. With this elements our architecture is ready:

#Model

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
  # Network architecture
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu", input_shape = p) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 64, activation = "relu") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 3, activation = "softmax") %>%
  # Backpropagation
  compile(
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
    metrics = c('accuracy')
  )
```

With the architecture ready, we can train the model with `fit()` function. It has some arguments related to the working of the architecture like `epochs` and `batch_size`. It also does some validation with a percentage of data defined in `validation_split`. The code for training is next:

```
#Train the model
fit1 <- model %>%
  fit(
    x = mn_x,
    y = mn_y,
    epochs = 25,
    batch_size = 128,
    validation_split = 0.2,
    verbose = FALSE
  )
```

The results from our model are saved in `model1`. With this object you can explore results and make diagnosis of how good is the neural network. You can see the results from the model with this:

```
#Print
fit1
```

Output:

```
Trained on 84 samples (batch_size=128, epochs=25)
Final epoch (plot to see history):
    loss: 0.3645
     acc: 0.8452
val_loss: 0.656
 val_acc: 0.5238
```

Where values of loss and accuracy can be seen. You can also explore inidicators for the model with next code:

```
#Print
min(fit1$metrics$val_loss)
max(fit1$metrics$val_acc)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.6556502
[1] 1
```

Furthermore, you can visualize the evolution of accuracy and loss across iterations defined in `epoch`:

```
# Plot
plot(fit1)
```

Output:

[image]

The architecture defined in `model` can be tuned with other options like `kernel_regularizer` and others. You can explore more about the topic in the `keras` and `R` page if you are interested.

Comment: I've followed your advice, downloaded and installed all the necessary packages however I keep being faced with the following error: Error: "Python module tensorflow.keras was not found." I have downloaded Keras and Tensor Flow and Miniconda (via CRAN and via Github) but the problem persists.

Comment: @Chickpea1993 Did you installed the Python distribution oy your PC? Try that. It is strange because when you dowload keras to R, Anaconda distribution uses to be installed! Please check this https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.html

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of Python installed. I have also carefully used the link that you shared. It's bizarre. Right after completing each installation (after receiving a message that says TensorFlow has been installed), I run 'tensorflow::tf_config()' but am told that TensorFlow hasn't been installed yet.

Comment: It looks like an issue with the package. I shared a function to install the last version of tensorflow in your new question as comment. Please try that.